# ¿Como cambiar el Idioma de Ingles a Español a un calendario utilizando kendo UI?

Tags: php, javascript, html

estiy utilizando el Frameworks Kendo UI en un sitio web que 
estoy creando, estoy tratando de colocar un calendario pero quisiera que el idioma sea español he investigado pero no encuentro nada que me ayude, espero que me puedan apoyar a resolver este problema, muchas gracias.

Les dejo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
<script>
$("#dtFechaRecepcion").kendoDatePicker(); 
</script>

<input id="dtFechaRecepcion" value="Mes / Día / Año" title="datepicker" style="width: 100%" />
```

Espero me puedan ayudar con esto, mil gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que incluir el archivo en español y luego especificar la cultura asi:

```
<script src="js/cultures/kendo.culture.es-ES.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>

<script>
$("#dtFechaRecepcion").kendoDatePicker({
    culture: "es-ES"
}); 
</script>

<input id="dtFechaRecepcion" value="Mes / Día / Año" title="datepicker" style="width: 100%" />
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudaste a resolver mi duda.

Comment: De nada Vivi, para eso estamos